# How do I pass data from inside a Google Earth Balloon to the hosting application?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I have a desktop application that includes a Google Earth web browser plugin and many other 'pages' and controls.  My goal is for the user to hover over a placemark, a balloon pops up with a button inside and by pressing that button I want to pass data back to the application so I can change 'pages' away from the GE Browser.  I already have the balloon popping up and the button in place but I don't know how to tell the application that the button has been pressed.

Any ideas?

```
                    dynamic placemark = KmlHelpers.CreatePlacemark(
                                        ge1,
                                        Coord,
                                        d.sSerialNumber,    // ID (ESN)
                                        d.sNickname,     // Name - shown in tree
                                        "Device Type: " + d.sName + "\n" +
                                        "IP Address: " + d.sIPAddress + "\n" +
                                        "ESN: " + d.sSerialNumber + "\n" +
                                        "<button type=\"button\">Click</button>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put Javascript code in a balloon, you can follow this example:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#javascript_in_balloons

Comment: Hi Paco, thanks for responding.  I can put javascript in the balloon but I don't see how to pass the information from the javascript to the application that is hosting the browser.  Meaning, I have a C# managed code application with am embedded browser and I need to pass information back to the C# code.

Comment: I think you can make a method in your c# app an invoke in javascript like:     `application.method(variables);`[see this link as reference](http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/AddEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do it exactly the way I had wanted but here is how I was able to pass data from a balloon to the application.

I created a balloon with an html link as shown above but instead of the button line I replaced it with the following line:

```
"<a href=\"http://localhost/index.html#\"" + SerialNum + "\">Details</a>");
```

I created an EventListener for the Browser's 'Navigating' event.

In the EventListener function I stopped the browser from going to the URL using:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

where e is the argument list that comes into the function.

The link is validated before the navigating event is called so it has to be a 'good' URL.

It sure isn't elegant but it works.  Maybe some day I'll figure our how to do it better.  Until then...